# How do I set up a database for Symfony2 using Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm following the Symfony book and arrived at [the chapter on dealing with the database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html). I have a few questions, and can't seem to find an answer.

I'm just following the parameters.yml file that I have looks like this (auto-generated)

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: myproject
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
    debug_toolbar: true
    debug_redirects: false
    use_assetic_controller: true
```

Then I head over to the terminal and enter:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

I receive the following error:

```
Could not create database for connection named `myproject`
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

I have a few questions:

- How do I fix this
- Where is the database server? Did it come when I installed Symfony2 with Composer?

Comment: @dave I have MAMP installed, tested the MySQL-server and it is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long search I found it. It had something to do with the mysql.default_socket as pointed out in the comments.

MAMP showed me the socket was

```
':/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

After doing some more searching, I found that the socket can be set in config.yml, here:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    driver:   "%database_driver%"
    [...]
    unix_socket: "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock"
    [...]
```

If the unix_socket line is not there, just add it. Then tried to execute the same command in Terminal, which gave this result:

```
Created database for connection named `myproject`
```

And the database was really created.

Comment: For those who still can't resolve this problem, try to enable `Allow network access to MySQL` in MAMP settings.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony doesn't install mysql I assume you are working in a lamp stack.

If I remember well it happened to me once and I changed database_host:  127.0.0.1 to localhost and it worked well since.

Comment: I have a working MAMP-installation. Just updated the database_host to localhost. The error is changed to:

Could not create database for connection named `myproject`
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Comment: Are you using  the standard mysql port 3306 in MAMP? If not you have to change database_port: null to whatever port you are using in Mamp

Comment: The settings in MAMP are as follows:


Host  localhost
Port  3306
User  root
Password  root

And this is in parameters.yml

database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: localhost
database_port: 3306
database_name: myproject
database_user: root
database_password: root

Comment: The MySQL client knows that 'localhost' means the local machine, so it tries to connect to a Unix socket instead of making a network request. The problem here is that you're either not using a Unix socket, or--probably more likely--the MySQL client libraries don't know where to find the Unix socket file.  
Try to comment  in php.ini this: mysql.default_socket = 
so to use uses the built-in MySQL defaults.  
You should also restart mamp server

Comment: Thank you, your socket comment has aided me in finding the solution!